# Limit bytes to read from HTTP response

Tags: http, go

I need to read responses from user provided URLs

I don't want them to overload my server with links to huge files.

I want to read N bytes max and return an error if there are more bytes to read.

I can read N bytes, but how I detect, that file is incomplete (assuming corner cases when remote file is exactly N bytes long)?

Comment: Read until you find the Content-Length header, then you decide if you want to continue or not.

Comment: Read N+1 bytes. If the last byte is readable, the response is too long. If it's not, it's not.

Answer (score 7):

Additionally to Peter's answer, there is a ready solution in the [`net/http`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) package: [`http.MaxBytesReader()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#MaxBytesReader):

```
func MaxBytesReader(w ResponseWriter, r io.ReadCloser, n int64) io.ReadCloser
```

> MaxBytesReader is similar to io.LimitReader but is intended for limiting the size of incoming request bodies. In contrast to io.LimitReader, MaxBytesReader's result is a ReadCloser, returns a non-EOF error for a Read beyond the limit,  and closes the underlying reader when its Close method is called.

Originally it was "designed" for limiting the size of incoming *request* bodies, but it can be used to limit incoming *response* bodies as well. For that, simply pass `nil` for the `ResponseWriter` parameter.

Example using it:

```
{
    body := ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer([]byte{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}))
    r := http.MaxBytesReader(nil, body, 4)
    buf, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r)
    fmt.Println("When body is large:", buf, err)
}

{
    body := ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer([]byte{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}))
    r := http.MaxBytesReader(nil, body, 5)
    buf, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r)
    fmt.Println("When body is exact (OK):", buf, err)
}

{
    body := ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer([]byte{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}))
    r := http.MaxBytesReader(nil, body, 6)
    buf, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r)
    fmt.Println("When body is small (OK):", buf, err)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2GlegE7VPZC)):

```
When body is large: [0 1 2 3] http: request body too large
When body is exact (OK): [0 1 2 3 4] <nil>
When body is small (OK): [0 1 2 3 4] <nil>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply try to read your maximum acceptable size plus 1 byte. For an acceptable size of 1MB:

```
var res *http.Response

b := make([]byte, 1<<20+1)
n, err := io.ReadFull(res.Body, b)
switch err {
case nil:
    log.Fatal("Response larger than 1MB")
case io.ErrUnexpectedEOF:
    // That's okay; the response is exactly 1MB or smaller.
    b = b[:n]
default:
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

You can also do the same thing with an [io.LimitedReader](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#LimitedReader):

```
var res *http.Response

r := &io.LimitedReader{
    R: res.Body,
    N: 1<<20 + 1,
}

// handle response body somehow
io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, r)

if r.N == 0 {
    log.Fatal("Response larger than 1MB")
}
```

Note that both methods limit the *uncompressed* size. Significantly fewer bytes may traverse the network if the response is compressed. You need be clear about whether you want to limit network or memory usage and adjust the limit accordingly, possibly on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the content length field in request header to get the total file size.

Comment: Not all responses have Content-Length

Comment: and the content length should not be trusted to match the actual size